# How can I tell when a thread have finished when using a thread pool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

My thread:

```
public void main_news_thread(MainApplication main)
{
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(p => check_news(validrsslist, 0));
}
```

I call this thread every interval of time...

How can I know when the thread finishes so I can call two other methods which deal with the GUI? How can I refer to this threadpool thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are talking about UI, you might want to look at BackgroundWorker, which offers a RunWorkerCompleted event that fires **on the UI thread**, and indicate success/failure/cancel etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker_events.aspx

Personally, though, I'd just run a callback method at the end of my worker code (remembering to switch back to the UI thread, via Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF or this.Invoke in winforms).

Comment: +1 The `BackgroundWorker` is a wrapper around the thread pool. It provides all the code he would have to write manually. Asynchronous Delegates also schedule work on the thread pool. In other words: don't use the `ThreadPool` directly. Use an object that wraps the thread pool with useful extras, such as "complete" callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the methods in the thread itself (you have to take care of invoking yourself to access the gui thread):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(p => {
                                    check_news(validrsslist, 0);
                                    //do something after the task is finished
                                  });
```

Comment: Thats the problam How can i access the GUI thread or change any controls from this thread? maybe i can call a mathod from the main thread (somehow tell this new thread to call a mathod of the main thread?)